# Weird Date Format To Java Date

Tags: java

I got the following date format that I get from an API (Yes I tried to get them to change the API... dailywtf story):

```
\/Date(1310481956000+0200)\/
```

How can I convert this into a Java Date? (java.util.Date)

This comes from a .NET JSON web service.

Comment: What does that format stand for in the first place? How does it work? Is it a timestamp?

Comment: I think this format is used in JSON on some .NET services.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without knowing what the date/time string stands for, let me make a guess.

The `1310481956000` looks to be milliseconds after epoch, and the `+0200` an offset relative to GMT.

The following code seem to indicate it as well:

```
final TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+0200");
final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(tz);
cal.setTimeInMillis(1310481956000L);
final SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
f.setTimeZone(tz);
System.out.println(f.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Prints `2011-07-12 16:45:56 GMT+02:00`

Comment: I have converted a date into String `"MM/dd/yyyy"` format. I want to parse the converted date into `"MM/dd/yyyy"` format of `Java.util.Date`. But the output format is changing to `"2011-07-12 16:45:56 GMT+02:00"` format. I want keep in the current format("MM/dd/yyyy"). But need in Java.util.Date **NOT STRING**. Any help please...

Comment: @vissu pepala Dates in Java are internally just integers, and the default date output format is entirely system/locale-dependent. If you want to output dates in a specific format, specify the format using `SimpleDateFormat` as above.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I convert this into a Java Date? (java.util.Date)

First, get "them" to clearly and precisely tell you exactly what that date format means.  (If they won't or can't you could guess; see below.)

Next write a custom parser to parse the String and extract the information content.

Finally, convert the information content into a form that matches one of the `Date` constructors and create an instance.

---

My guess is that the `1310481956000` part is the number of milliseconds since the UNIX epoch (1970/01/01T00:00) and that the `0200` represents a timezone offset of 2 hours (MET?).  However, you shouldn't rely on a guess.  Get "them" to give you the specification, or at least a number of examples and the actual times/timezones that they correspond to.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to get the format from the API provider but it seems like a [epoch](http://www.epochconverter.com/) + an offset for time zones.  To convert it you could try.

```
final String fromAPI = "1310481956000+0200"
final String epochTime = fromAPI.substring(0, fromAPI.indexOf("+"));
final String timeZoneOffSet = fromAPI.substring(fromAPI.indexOf("+"), fromAPI.size());

Date date = new Date(Long.parseLong(epochTime));
```

**Notice i'm not doing anything with the time zone** (if that's what it is).  You'll have to deal with that but this should get you on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli( 
    java.lang.Long.parseLong( "1310481956000" )
).atOffset( ZoneOffset.of( "+0200" ) )
```

## Using java.time

The [accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7131228/642706) is correct but outdated. The modern way to handle this is through the java.time classes.

The input is ambiguous. Is it a count from the [Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) [epoch reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) date-time of first moment of 1970 in UTC `1970-01-01T00:00:00:Z` and then adjusted by two hours ahead of UTC? If so, this example code seen here works.

First parse that input number as a `Instant`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

Extract the first portion of your string and parse as a `long`.

```
long millisSinceEpoch = java.lang.Long.parseLong( "1310481956000" );
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( millisSinceEpoch );
```

> instant.toString(): 2011-07-12T14:45:56Z

Extract the last portion of your string and parse as a `ZoneOffset`.

```
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.of( "+0200" );
```

Apply the offset to the `Instant` to get an `OffsetDateTime`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( offset );
```

> odt.toString(): 2011-07-12T16:45:56+02:00

Note that an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) is not a time zone. A zone is an offset *plus* a set of rules for handling anomalies such as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).

Avoid `java.util.Date` whenever possible. But if you must use one, you can convert to/from java.time. Look to new conversion methods added to the old classes.

```
java.util.Date d = java.util.Date.from( odt.toInstant() );
```

> d.toString(): Tue Jul 12 14:45:56 GMT 2011

See [live code at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/s6Ar5P) covering this entire example.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).